# Flask socket.io not working in thread

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I have a python server which runs a thread and emits a signal via websocket:

```
def read_serial():
   while True:
      ...
      socketio.emit("fire", {'n': 1},  namespace='/test')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '32ed21l31f9031kd93'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)
...
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target = read_serial)
    thread.start()
    socketio.run(app, use_reloader=True)
```

On the client side I have the next code:

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + "/test");

socket.on('fire', function(data){
    fireTimer(data.n);
});
```

Connection is working, but events are not being fired as supposed to do.

Comment: Do you have eventlet or gevent installed in your virtual environment? If yes, which one? Are you doing anything in the `read_serial` function that can be blocking? That could be the problem.

Comment: @Miguel Im having the same problem too. I have eventlet installed. a connection is made the app runs but the events don't fire

Comment: @Zion write a separate question with your code. As I said above, my guess is that you are doing something that blocks, which cannot happen when you are working with eventlet or gevent, but can't really tell you the specifics without seeing what you've done.

Comment: @Miguel it's ok I got it to work. it was an import problem. Im currently following your scalable folder structure that you recommended as well as using an app factory and there seemed to have been some conflict with the imports but that was resolved.

but the problem now is. if you need to do `socketio.run(app)` to `run` the `app` how do you do that when you are in heroku?

Comment: @Zion on Heroku you have to use gunicorn to run the server. See the Flask-SocketIO docs. And also note that there is currently a suspected gunicorn bug in version 19.x that prevents websocket from working in Heroku. The 18.0 version of gunicorn works fine.

Comment: @Miguel that might be why. I'll try the 18.0 version of gunicorn. I got my apps running on heroku it's just the websockets that were the problem and I learned a bit of heroku from your O'reilly videos. Those videos single handedly taught me flask and web dev. It's amazing! I hope you'd have more of those soon.